# Is Java allow stack allocated objects in java 10?

Tags: java

Is Java allow stack allocated objects in java 10? what are main features addon in java 10 as per memory point of view?

Comment: [Have a look at this for some 'main' new features](https://dzone.com/articles/java-10-released-10-new-features-devs-should-know)

Comment: There are no version numbers associated with value types. Take a look at OpenJDK for status updates.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in Java 10 or any older version of Java to explicitly allocate objects on the stack.

However, one of the optimizations that has been in Java's virtual machine for a few years already is [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) (at least in Oracle's JVM implementation). The JVM can detect whether some objects are used only inside a method, and then automatically allocate them on the stack instead of on the heap.

More details:

- [Escape Analysis](https://dzone.com/articles/escape-analysis) in the JVM
- [Overview of Java's Escape Analysis](https://dzone.com/articles/overview-of-javas-escape-analysis)

Note that this is an advanced subject that you normally do not need to be worried about as a Java programmer, and you do not need to have in-depth knowledge about if you are studying for a Java programming certification exam.

See the [JDK 10 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html) to learn what's new in JDK 10.

Comment: I am assuming he is referring to [JEP 169](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169), which will be available in the future.

Comment: Yes; JEP 169 is not in Java 10.

Comment: Yes, I know. Others might be interested in what he’s referring to, though.